# Drawing multiple rectangles into image in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I am trying to draw rectangles into QML. Data, which contains info about those rectangles, looks like this:

- X
- Y
- Width
- Height
- Data

Data are stored in array and each item in array represents one rectangle. I am looking for best (or at least a good) way to draw those rectangles.

Which component of QML should I use?

**class.h**

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<structure> list READ list NOTIFY listChanged)
    public:
        QList<structure> list() const { return list_; }
    signals:
        listChanged();
    private:
        QList<structure> list_;
}
```

**repeater.qml**

```
Repeater {
    model: 2 
    delegate: Rectangle{
        width: model.list.width
        height: model.list.height
        x: model.list.x
        y:  model.list.y
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

Comment: Data contains another Data?

Comment: Have you tried a `Repeater`? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Could the X, Y, Width or Height properties be modified later?, 
If so, a better option is a model 
with a Repeater

Comment: Where store the data? QML or C++?

Comment: @Jiu C++, in structure

Comment: @derM Tried Repeater

Comment: @eyllanesc No, they are not editable. I read them from file, and they can't be changed.

Comment: Then please show, how you tried the repeater. I guess most of our questions are answered once you provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Than maybe someone might help you.

Comment: @Brykyz then create a  list of QRect and export it to QML, it uses a Repeater.

Comment: @Brykyz as derM says, show what you've tried and we've given you clues to the solution.

Comment: @Jiu 
I think we have to leave it to him for a while to try something and when we have a real problem we can help him. :)

Comment: @derM added minimal example, somehow I can't expose QList of structures into QML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not necessary to create a `QObject`, just a `QVariantList` that stores the `QRect` is enough. On the other hand the model that you have to pass is just the list of `QRect`, to access each `QRect` in the delegate you must use `modelData`.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include <QRect>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QVariantList rectlist;
    rectlist<< QRect{50, 30, 100, 100}
            << QRect{200, 20, 30, 30}
            <<QRect{300, 300, 200, 33}
           <<QRect{400, 23, 44, 55};

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("rectlist", rectlist);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Repeater {
        model: rectlist
        delegate: Rectangle{
            x: modelData.x
            y: modelData.y
            width: modelData.width
            height: modelData.height
            color: "red"
        }
    }    
}
```

[image]

---

**Update:**

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QColor>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include <QRect>

struct Data
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(QRect rect MEMBER rect)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text MEMBER text)
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor color MEMBER color)
public:
    QRect rect;
    QString text;
    QColor color;
    Data(const QRect& rect= QRect(), const QString& text="", const QColor& color = QColor(Qt::transparent)){
        this->rect = rect;
        this->text = text;
        this->color = color;
    }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Data)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QVariantList rectlist;
    rectlist <<QVariant::fromValue( Data{ QRect{50, 30, 100, 100}, "text1", Qt::red});
    rectlist <<QVariant::fromValue( Data{ QRect{200, 20, 30, 30 }, "text2", QColor("blue")});
    rectlist <<QVariant::fromValue( Data{ QRect{300, 300, 200,33}, "text3", QColor(0, 200, 0)});
    rectlist <<QVariant::fromValue( Data{ QRect{400, 23, 44, 55 }, "text4"});

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("rectlist", rectlist);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Repeater {
        model: rectlist
        delegate: Rectangle{
            x: modelData.rect.x
            y: modelData.rect.y
            width: modelData.rect.width
            height: modelData.rect.height
            color: modelData.color
            Text{
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: modelData.text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The important thing to note here for you, is **what is the model of the `Repeater`** and **how you access the model data**

Comment: Thank you, that worked, just a last question, if I want to add more data to structure (like QString), I need to make model, right?

Comment: @Brykyz No, it is not necessary, right now update the appropriate method, a model is when you want to handle tasks such as reorder, add, delete, modify, etc, but in your case it is not necessary since the data is static.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you very much!